# How to display Horizontal Tab using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have XML and XSLT and I am using XSLT to Transform XML Data.

Now the problem which I am facing is:
I am able to detect Tab Character code `&#x09;` but not able to print it on HTML.
I am displaying output in `<span>` Tag.
I have used XSLT template and below is small code snippet which I am using to print Horizontal Tag. Below output will be wrapped in `<span>` Tag.

```
<xsl:if test="substring($text,1,1) = '&#x09;'">
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

If I use `&#45;` then it prints `-` sign properly but not print Horizontal Tab.
Does anybody has any Idea?

Comment: Show php Show php Show php

Comment: Horizontal Tab is *whitespace*.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Everything is working fine only having issue with Horizontal Tab

Comment: @proskor, you're right but what if user copies texts with Horizontal Tab? Then how to display it in HTML using XSLT?

Comment: Replace `&#09;` with 4 spaces

Comment: @php_nub_qq, First I did that but then it stores white spaces in xml and then it creates problem. Because in xml too I am storing Tab character.

Comment: Don't store it with spaces, replace on display

Comment: @php_nub_qq: I have inline content editing on Textarea. So I don't have control once user click and edit the content. :(

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Can't `<span>` tag shows Tab space?

Comment: @proskor: Can't <span> tag shows Tab space?

Comment: It is very hard to understand your situation for me but here're the simplest solutions that come to mind:
1. Save data with the hex value in the database and then when you're about to display it replace the pattern with 4 spaces.  
2. Have a class at your spans or attribute that indicates the level of tabs and then use javascript to add `text-indent` with `level*10` as pixels for example

Comment: Ok. I try to do that way.

Comment: HTML browsers treat all whitespace equally: spaces, tabs, line breaks are collapsed and displayed as one single space, with the exception of content nested in a `<pre>` element. However, `&nbsp;` are not collapsed and therefore can be used to display longer spaces by appending many of them. But first, you should distinguish between how you *store* your data and how you *display / enter* it. Using multiple `&nbps;` to represent tabs on display doesn't mean you should store them in your database (or xml files or whatever) that way. You need to convert your data between storage and presentation.

Comment: @proskor: So it means I cannot use Tab code to represent Tab Space in Span, right? Ok. I go to check as you suggested. :)

Comment: That's right, it would just look like a single space.

Comment: I solved this problem by using <xsl:value-of select="&#09;"/> instead of xsl:text elements.

Answer (score 2):

I had to same problem and I solved it with:

```
&#x3000; --> empty char
```

It is an completely empty char, but smaller than a tab. It looks like this: "　".

(I was going to place as comment, but you need 50 points to do that...)